# How to configure MapStruct to throw an exception when enum values can't be mapped

Tags: java, enums, mapstruct

This is my Mapper:

```java
@Mapper
public interface ProductMapper {
    ProductClassification toProductClassification(ProductTypes pisType);
}
```

Where `ProductTypes` and `ProductClassification` are enums. I want it to throw an exception when it can't map the enums, but I get compiler error:
`The following constants from the source enum have no corresponding constant in the target enum and must be be mapped via adding additional mappings: EXTERNAL, UNKNOWN.`

I tried with `@ValueMappings` annotation, but can only configure it to set the value to null, which is not sufficient:

```java
@ValueMappings({
    @ValueMapping(source = MappingConstants.ANY_REMAINING, target = MappingConstants.NULL)
})
```

What would be the right way to configure MapStruct mapper to throw an exception when it can't map enum constants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using `MappingConstants.THROW_EXCEPTION` and setting it to a `ValueMapping#target`.

So in this example in order to throw an exception for any remaining mapping you can write:

```
@ValueMapping(source = MappingConstants.ANY_REMAINING, target = MappingConstants.THROW_EXCEPTION)
```

**Note** this is available from version 1.5

Comment: Could you please update your comment, this feature is finally available

Comment: Good point. Just updated the answer